# Filtering the text output in linux

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk, sed

I get output from Junos Switches in such format:

```
Physical interface: ge-0/0/7, Enabled, Physical link is Up
Queue counters:    Queued packets  Transmitted packets   Dropped packets
  0 N4M-Q1                   0          42210774942              1163342
```

I need only the interface name and dropped packets value in one line, something like this:

```
ge-0/0/7 - 1163342
```

I tried many different combination of `sed` and `awk`. I tried to merge 3 lines to get only the columns I need, but it did not work.
This is how I tried to merge lines:

```
cat file.txt.out | awk '{getline b; getline c;printf("%s %s %s\n",$0,b,c)}'
```

But it seems the resulting line is too long, so i was not able to get what is needed. Please help

The output looks like this(but much longer):

```
Physical interface: ge-0/0/0, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0              4582206                    0
Physical interface: ge-0/0/1, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          14419826529               112564
Physical interface: ge-0/0/2, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          67593521901              1675707
Physical interface: ge-0/0/3, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          44283738671               977315
Physical interface: ge-0/0/4, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          98998665742              5065245
Physical interface: ge-0/0/5, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          56932179711              1446413
Physical interface: ge-0/0/6, Enabled, Physical link is Up
  Queue counters:       Queued packets  Transmitted packets      Dropped packets
    0 N4M-Q1                         0          34955222648               578513
```

Comment: With `awk` you can say something like `awk -F"[ :,]" 'NR==1{print $4} END{print $NF}'`. This prints the 3rd block of text in the first line and the last one in the last line.

Comment: sed is for simple substitutions on individual lines. That is all. You never need sed if you are already using awk. Do not use getline in awk until you have read and fully understand http://awk.info/?tip/getline and have a good working knowledge of the rest of awk. You never need to use `cat` just to open a file - most UNIX tools can do that just fine for themselves (`cmd file`) and for the rest shell redirection can do it (`cmd < file`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's extremely hard to guess with just one block of sample input, but this may be what you want:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{print $3, $NF}' file
ge-0/0/7, 1163342
```

If not, post a few blocks of your input file instead of just one so we can get a better idea what it is you're trying to parse.

Given your newly posted sample input, this is what you need:

```
$ awk '(NR%3)==1{p=$3} (NR%3)==0{print p, $NF}' file
ge-0/0/0, 0
ge-0/0/1, 112564
ge-0/0/2, 1675707
ge-0/0/3, 977315
ge-0/0/4, 5065245
ge-0/0/5, 1446413
ge-0/0/6, 578513
```

Comment: I have added more output. Your solution looks cool, but as i understand it only works for one block of output.

Comment: Alex - no, it works for multiple blocks of input (`records` to awk) but the blocks would need to be separated from each other by a blank line. I'll take a look at what you have now. OK, I just posted an updated solution.

Comment: Ed, this works great. Thank you. Could you please explain a little how it works.

Comment: Sure, but could you take a guess and I'll correct you if wrong? I bet you guess right first time. Hint: `NR` is the current line number in the file.

Comment: Ed, sorry for late response. So, as i understand first three lines are joined into one using this part: `(NR%3)==1`, then variable p takes the valued contained int the 3rd line of the merged long line. `(NR%3)==0`  - this part is unclear to me, unfortunately. And the last is to print the content of p and the last column. That's how i see this.

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) in awk and many other languages. `NR` is the current count of how many records (lines in your case) have been read. So `NR%3` is the number of lines mod 3 so when you're at line 1 the result of that mod op is 1, at 2 it's 2 and at 3 it's 0. Then at 4 it's 1, 5 it's 2, and 6 is 0. And so on. So `p` gets set at lines 1, 4, 7, etc. and `p, $0` gets printed at lines 3, 6, 9, etc. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Totally fragile:

```
$ cat test.txt
Physical interface: ge-0/0/7, Enabled, Physical link is Up
Queue counters:    Queued packets  Transmitted packets   Dropped packets
  0 N4M-Q1                   0          42210774942              1163342

$ echo $(grep -Po "Physical interface: \K[^,]*" test.txt) "-" \
       $(awk '!/Phys/ && !/Drop/ && NF {print $NF}' test.txt)

ge-0/0/7 - 1163342
```

This works like this:

- `grep -Po "Physical interface: \K[^,]*" test.txt` get all the text after `Physical interface:` and up to a comma.
- `awk '!/Phys/ && !/Drop/ && NF {print $NF}' test.txt` in those lines not containing `Phys`, nor `Drop` nor being empty, print the last field.

You can also use `printf` to have more control over the content your are printing:

```
printf "%s - %s\n" $(grep -Po "Physical interface: \K[^,]*" test.txt) $(awk '!/Phys/ && !/Drop/ && NF {print $NF}' test.txt)
```

Comment: no problem :) Note than also `phys/dropp` filtering out can be inserted into awk by saying `awk '!/Phys/ && !/Drop/`

Comment: @fedorqui, thanks again, I'm learning just as much as OP probably :)

Comment: Haha glad to read that! I like the way you are doing `grep -o`. You can even use a look behind and say `grep -Po "Physical interface: \K[^,]*"`. This way, by saying `\K` your kind of clean the previous match and just print what goes next.

Comment: @fedorqui, from some useless invocations and pipes down to a `grep` and `awk` held together by an `echo`. Looks much better now, thanks!

Comment: You never need grep if you're using awk. Your command could be rewritten in many ways in just one awk command, including (for ease of comparison against what you have) `awk '/Physical interface:/{p=$3} !/Phys/ && !/Drop/ && NF {print p, $NF}' test.txt`.

Comment: @EdMorton, thanks - my awk-fu is not strong enough, but I am working on it.

Comment: I recommend anyone learning awk get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins. If you have any other awk book, throw it away as it's out of date at best.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after almost 2 days of struggling (I am a beginner in unix scripting) i have got this:

```
 cat myfile | sed -n -e '/Physical/,$p' | egrep -v 'Dropped|master' | awk '{gsub(/Physical interface:|Enabled,|Physical link is|0 N4M-Q1/,"")}1' | sed '/^\s*$/d' | sed -e 's/  \+/ /g' | xargs -n 4 | awk '{ print $1" "$4 }'
```

Which produces such result:

```
ge-0/0/0, 0
ge-0/0/1, 112564
ge-0/0/2, 1675707
ge-0/0/3, 977315
ge-0/0/4, 5065245
ge-0/0/5, 1446413
ge-0/0/6, 578513
ge-0/0/7, 1163342
ge-0/0/8, 1297
ge-0/0/9, 1604987
```

I realize that this soution might not be the most optimal, but at least it does what i need;) "Optimization" proposals are appreciated:)

Comment: this is completely unoptimized :O I don't know what is best here: is this a final solution you found yourself? In general, posting an answer to your answer is not a bad idea if it *is* an answer. But if it is an extra question, you better edit your original question and post it there. Also, it is good to provide feedback to the answers you got and, eventually, accept one.